# Extract list elements between lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, components, extract

I have the following list:

```
[[a,b,c],
 [d,e,f],
 [g,h,i]]
```

and would like to get the following (e.g. if I extract 0th element of a list within the list):

```
[[a],[d],[g]]
```

I've been able to do it for one element (e.g. `([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]])!!0!!0 = a`) but I can't seem to get the function to work for all elements in that column.

Comment: How are you learning Haskell? Doing the same operation to all elements of a list is something very basic and taught quite soon.

Comment: Incidentally, using `(!!)` on lists is not good style and lends itself to producing bad, inefficient code. It's exceedingly rare to only want a single element from the middle of a list, and when extracting multiple elements repeatedly there are much better ways to do it. You're obviously very new to Haskell, so I'd encourage you to avoid using `(!!)` at all until you get a better feel for using lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already know that you can use `!! i` to get the `i`th element of a list. So how do you get the `i`th element of each list in a list of lists? By applying `(!! i)` to each list in the list of lists. And how do you do that? By using `map` which can apply any function to each element in a list.

So by using `map` with `(!! i)` we get a list containing the `i`th column of each row, which would be `[a, d, g]` in your example. From that you can get to your expected output easily enough.

Though if you want to access your matrix by column a lot, you might be better off [transposing](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3atranspose) your matrix once and then using the transposed matrix.

Comment: You might want to explain "transposing" in this context, as a lot of brains would just shut down as soon as you mention it, or matrix (as it's obvious you don't mean the movie).

Comment: @shintoist: Besides logic and other topics often taught directly in CS courses, linear algebra is *by far* the most useful area of "advanced" math for programmers to know. It's not at all unreasonable to expect familiarity with the terms, or at least sufficient recognition to go look them up on Wikipedia. There's absolutely no excuse whatsoever for a programmer's brain "shutting down" at the mere mention of common terminology.

Comment: Note that linking in [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) is pretty trivial :) -- best of both worlds. No clutter for those who paid attention in their high school math classes, easy link to definitive guide for those who haven't made it there yet. :)

Comment: @camccann not all programmers are CS majors, my friend. As this is obviously a beginner question it deserves a beginner answer, as I was pointing out. You are right that advanced math is useful to know, but a person is under no obligation to learn it just to be able to come here to ask questions, are they?

Comment: @shintoist: Basic coverage of matrices is pretty common, one would have to avoid any sort of math beyond elementary algebra to not see the terms. But yes, for an extremely beginner question like this, you're right that simple phrasing is better. Also, I do think there's an obligation to be *willing to learn from an answer*, which is why an inline link as @sarnold suggests is ideal.

Answer (score 3):

To extract first element of list, you can use `head` function, so if you want to extract first elements of lists contained within a list, you should write

```
extract_first :: [[a]] -> [a]
extract_first = map head
```

Comment: Thanks.How would I go about it if I wanted the second elements or third elements contained within a list though?

Comment: As others have said you can use !! (but it's generally bad to use it as you shouldn't think of lists as arrays).  Take a look at the Data.List module and you should see lots of helpful functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a second function to get the second of the list, and use the cool map snd'!

```
snd' :: [a] -> a
snd' [] = error "can't call the second on an empty list!"
snd' [x] = error "can't call the second when the list has only one value!"
snd' (_:x:_) = x
```

Comment: Why would you write an own function? `snd` is in the standard library.